# Unexpected user agent stylesheet at chrome browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, user-agent

I'm seeing an unexpected user agent spreadsheet being used to hide a div. I say unexpected because it does not show anywhere else where Chrome's user agent spreadsheets are documented, such as https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css:

[image: user agent spreadsheet defines class .socio with display set to none and important attribute]

I don't know much about how this works but I'm going crazy over it. I know it does not happen if I use incognito mode, but it shows up on regular mode.

Any clue on where this is coming from? This is causing some items on my web page to be hidden.

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.socio` css class comes from uBlockOrigins filters (or another ad blocker you may have installed)

https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets
[Specific line of code here](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/blob/a73010944104a024f27e9e85e12a7ff4b7dcc072/thirdparties/easylist/easylist-social.txt#L11422)

Please try and load the page with uBlockOrigin turned off and see if the problem still persists

Comment: and the extension doesn't run (by default) in incognito

Comment: I tested with Adblock Plus disabled on that website and it fixed the issue. Thank you!